how to trigger next processor only after the queue gets empty

querydatabasetable --> fetch data from source approx 2GB data.

convertavrotojson ---> converting avro fromat data to json format

putdatabaserecord --> ingesting all the 2GB (10 million above records) to postgresql.


as the queue threshold is 10,000. i have given flowfile expiration for 2 seconds for the success of putdatabaserecord. so after all the data is ingested and flowfile is empty after expiration i need to trigger the next executesql processor to run stored procedures. so how to trigger next processor after putdatabserecord processor.
i used rest api to check queue size whether less than 0 or greater than 0. if less than 0 then only it calls stored procedure. but how to trigger invokehttp (rest api) or  executesql to call procedure only after ingestion is completed.

If you are using Max Rows Per Flow File parameter then QueryDatabaseTable writes the following attributes into a resulted flow files:
fragment.identifier  - the same result set will have the same value
fragment.count       - number of fragments
fragment.index       - index of current fragment

after PutDatabaseRecord you can redirect success relationship to MergeContent with approximately following params:
Merge Strategy = Defragment
Merge Format   = ZIP

This should wait when all fragments combined into one zip file - means all processed. The output of this processor is your trigger.
I see flow as:
querydatabasetable -->
convertavrotojson  -->
putdatabaserecord  -->
mergecontent       -->
execute sproc...



About Defragment strategy: Combines fragments that are associated by attributes back into a single cohesive FlowFile. If using this strategy, all FlowFiles must have the attributes fragment.identifier, fragment.count, and fragment.index. All FlowFiles with the same value for fragment.identifier will be grouped together. All FlowFiles in this group must have the same value for the fragment.count attribute. All FlowFiles in this group must have a unique value for the fragment.index attribute between 0 and the value of the fragment.count attribute.


thank you for the suggestion. i have expiration for the putdatabaserecord success. will mergecontent works then

if i give flowfile expiration for the success of putdatabaserecord then merge content is not working. Im expiring the success queue because if the queue count reaches 10000 then the data is getting holded in all queues thats the reason expiration is given to the succcess. as those records got ingested into database.  @daggett

make fragments larger or make queue larger. you still can try to use your initial idea - invokehttp, and schedule it to trigger every 15 seconds for example
